# Should Factory Class' create() method be static? Or make Factory Class singleton?

Tags: java, singleton, factory-pattern

Title pretty much sums it up.

I have a factory class that will construct an instance of another class when it's `create()` method is called. I have setup my Factory Class to be a singleton, which forces invokation to look as such:

```
SomeClass clazz = (SomeClass) FactoryClass.getInstance().create(ENUM.TYPE);
```

This guarantees that my Factory is thread safe, but may cause blocking, etc.

If my factory was not a singleton, I could instead set my `.create()` method be `static`, which would achieve similar results.

```
SomeClass clazz = (SomeClass) FactoryClass.create(ENUM.TYPE);
```

Assuming multiple threads may attempt to create instances of objects via the FactoryClass, which is better? Don't both ways of doing this provide the same level of thread safety?

Comment: The thread safety would come from all necessary objects being created locally, ie. in the method body.

Comment: The singleton approach allows you to switch between multiple implementations of the factory.

Comment: @Detheroc as-in multiple factories? i'm not sure I understand, sorry.

Comment: In addition to @Detheroc: the singleton approach allows you to pass an (the) instance of the factory to another method.

Comment: @Heuster do you mean "the singleton approach allows..." ?

Comment: @SnakeDoc typo, corrected it :)

Comment: As an aside, shouldn't the `create` method return the desired type without having to cast? For example, a PizzaFactory should return a Pizza (which commonly would be an Interface), not an Object that needs to be cast by each caller.  Just my 2c.

Comment: @splungebob yes but a CheesePizza has methods that a Pizza does not, such as .eatCheese(). So in order to invoke .eatCheese(), one must cast to that type (CheesePizza in this case)... no?

Comment: @SnakeDoc Technically what you say is true. It's just in my experience, with any Factory I've written, the client code doesn't care about subclass-specific methods, only the ones exposed by the interface. Yes, there's a few oddball times where the client code got the instance, then later in the logic did a cast (under special circumstances) in order to gain access to a subclass-specific method. However, this would be rare. I was just commenting on the syntax of your `create` method which appears to force a cast. Of course, w/o seeing the signature of the method I could be wrong.

Comment: @splungebob hmm, interesting thoughts. i'm relatively new to the Factory pattern, so your input is valuable. Above was just a quick example, but in my codebase, my factory returns the type of the interface the object has implemented (which happens to be a JAXB xml object), which is then passed to other stuff to do processing logic. So casting isn't explicitly required unless you need access to the underlying setters and getters to modify the xml object in memory, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither has an impact on thread-safety. The threading issues reside in the `create` method's implementation. A static method could create an instance (or get the singleton) and call an instance method so there is really no difference.

Exposing the Singleton is simply an API choice in how you want it to look and feel.

That said, static methods are more challenging to mock in a testing environment so that might be something to consider.